# Identifiers in Molten data for ggplot

Tags: r, casting, ggplot2, melt

I am struggling a bit with `id.vars` in `melt()` and how to make it work with `ggplot()`.

Let's say I got this data on California Population by race, age, and gender since 1970:

```
ca1970_1989<-read.table(
 url('http://www.dof.ca.gov/research/demographic/data/race-ethnic/1970-89/documents/California.txt'),  
header=F,strip.white=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=T)
names(ca1970_1989)<-c('County name','Year','Sex','Age','Total Population','White Population','Hispanic Population','Asian & Pacific Islander Population','Black Population','American Indian Population')
```

I don't need age for the time being so I sum that away.

`ca1970_1989.agg<-aggregate(ca1970_1989[,6:10],by=list(ca1970_1989$Sex,ca1970_1989$Year),FUN=sum)`

I want to plot it with `ggplot()` so I melt as appropriate:

`ca1970_1989.m<-melt(ca1970_1989.agg, id.vars=c('Group.1','Group.2'))
names(ca1970_1989.m)[1:2]<-c('Sex','Year')`

```
> head(ca1970_1989.m)
     Sex Year         variable   value
1 FEMALE 1970 White Population 7845344
2   MALE 1970 White Population 7635379
3 FEMALE 1971 White Population 7848106
4   MALE 1971 White Population 7626582
5 FEMALE 1972 White Population 7827480
6   MALE 1972 White Population 7597465
```

I want to pass to ggplot, but let it properly know that there is, in fact, an extra identifier (Sex) so it can distinguish male and female values.

If I do this call, I don't capture the `Sex` grouping.

```
ggplot(ca1970_1989.m, aes(x=Year, y=value, group=variable), colour=variable)) +
geom_line()
```

Should I use `cast` to have `variable` be a combination of gender AND race? Should I use `melt()` differently with respect to the `id.vars` parameter in the first place?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't follow at all. You have a gender variable present in your data. Why wouldn't ggplot be able to use the variable `Sex` (if you told it to)?

Comment: I am using this call, so at issue is that I use `variable` as the grouping level. Can I use both `variable` and `Sex` ? `ggplot(ca1970_1989.m, aes(x=Year, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) +  geom_line()`

Comment: Use `interaction` or just `paste` the variables together.

Comment: @joran: is that the 'hack' way because I molted wrong/didn't cast or is that the most appropriate way to deal with multiple grouping levels?

Comment: I suspect (but could be wrong) that whatever anyone comes up with using `cast` or `reshape` will feel more complicated or "hackish" than what I suggested. Using `paste` is just one line. How is that a hack?

Comment: I just wasn't sure if I passed the right arguments to the melt() call upstream. Your solution definitely worked like a charm. You want to put paste and interaction as an answer and take the points?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two factors "Sex" and "variable" together with a colon, like this:

```
ggplot(ca1970_1989.m, aes(x=Year, y=value, group=variable:Sex),color=variable) + geom_line()
```

This worked for me on several occasions. But I am rather new to R, so it might just as well be that this is considered to be bad style.

Comment: That is quite succinct. Seems like it does the same thing as interaction() that @joran suggested for factors behind the scenes. Many ways to skin a chicken here :)